# Cannot access WCF url hosted as a windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, wcf-wshttpbinding

I have created a WCFLibrary which has :

```
   [OperationContract]
   string TestCall();
```

And my app.config has this :

```
  <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TestWCF.ITestService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TestWCF/TestService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

My Windowsservice has this :

```
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestWCF.TestService));
    }
```

Have compiled exe and installed it as a service everything is fine till this point.

Now I wanted to check this url from browser :

```
*http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TestWCF/TestService*
```

but due to some reasons I cant make a call to my WCF hosted in Windows Service, What might be went wrong am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestWCF.TestService));
    host.Open(); // :-)
}
```

Comment: MyBad MyBad.. How can I miss this single  line :D:D ..Thanks Legion ;)

Comment: Legion one more question hope you dont mind ..how can I make this IP from my app.config as a dynamic one and should ship seperately with exe.

Comment: you can use dns name or use overload serviceHost ctor `ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestWCF.TestService), baseAddress);`